# Electronic recommendation letter tips

Tags: recommendation-letter

Is it possible the recommendation letter be sent directly to the recruiter by the person who writes it?

Also, does the letter needs to be signed by hand? Maybe is enough to see that the letter comes directly from the sender, but is not signed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a letter writer, I either email the PDF directly to the hiring department or I use a letter service such as Interfolio. I never give it directly to the student.

I also insert both a scanned image of my signature as well as a digital cryptographic signature embedded into the PDF, with a note that the digital signature can be authenticated through Adobe Reader.

Comment: This sounds like a great procedure, although perhaps more involved than some use.

Comment: The scanned ink signature is already in my letterhead template. Adding the PDF digital signature adds a minute. For me, it's the requirement of sealing and signing the back of the envelope. Nonetheless, you're right, I rarely come across digital signatures as a recipient myself.